# Every executable must have an ELF header?

Tags: hex, elf

Every executable must have an ELF header?

Also i would like to know why libraries and header's properties are often associated with HEX values; what is this HEX related to? Why HEX and not just binary code or something else.

I'm referring to the HEX values that comes up with the use of `ldd` and `readelf` for example, the 2 utilities often used under linux.

This question is for a generic OS and is not targeting a specific one, the architecture is supposed to be X86 or ARM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every executable must have an ELF header

Yes, every ELF file begins with an ELF file header. If it doesn't, it's not a valid ELF file by definition.

> Why HEX and not just binary code or something else

You appear to be *very* confused about what HEX means. Any integer number can be written in many different representations. Decimal (base-10), octal (base-8), hex (base-16) are the most common ones, but base-20 is [not unheard of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigesimal). It's just a number, regardless of how you choose to represent it.